# Google Cloud Storage, posting from Node.js

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-storage

So I copied this Google [Cloud Storage JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage), and I have been trying to use it but whenever I deploy using "firebase deploy" it returns

```
Error: There was an unknown problem while trying to parse function triggers.
```

I believe, but am not sure, that I have narrowed it down to being these two lines as the source of the issues.

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

// Instantiate a storage client
const storage = new Storage();
```

Is there any additional setup I have to do other than just adding this to my server file? Do I need to add any credentials,...?

Comment: Can you please confirm the Firebase SDK version you have installed?

Comment: I think I am using Firebase Admin SDK

Answer (score 0):

1. For Error: There was an unknown problem while trying to parse
   function triggers.

   You can try to install the latest npm version npm install -g firebase-
   tools@latest
2. You can recheck with the below steps:

- Register and create project
- Enable Google Cloud Storage JSON API library
- Create a new credential
- Create a new bucket.

  const GoogleCloudStorage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

Please refer the document for detailed explanation [here](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/node-js-upload-file-to-google-cloud-storage)